# Is there $(f,S)\in X$ such that $\{x\in S\mid f(x)\neq 0\}$ does not have measure zero? ("Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres)

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

---

> Theorem 13.5(on p.109)
> Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded continuous function. Let $E$ be the set of points $\mathbf{x_0}$ of $\text{Bd}\,S$ for which the condition $$\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to\mathbf{x_0}} f(\mathbf{x})=0$$ fails to hold. If $E$ has measure zero, then $f$ is integrable over $S$.

---

It is difficult for me to grasp what this theorem is saying.

---

The author didn't write as follows:

> Theorem 13.5'
> Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded continuous function. If $\operatorname{Bd}S$ has measure zero, then $f$ is integrable over $S$.

---

Let
$$X:=\{(f,S)\mid S\text{ is a bounded set in }\mathbb{R}^n\text{ such that }\\\operatorname{Bd} S\text{ does not have measure zero. }\\f:S\to\mathbb{R}\text{ is a bounded continuous function and integrable over }S\}.$$

---

Let $S_1 = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{Q}^2 | 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1 \}$.
Then, $\operatorname{Bd}S_1=[0,1]\times [0,1]$ does not have measure zero.
Let $f_1$ be a function from $S_1$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_1(x)=0$ for any $x\in S_1$.
Then, $(f_1,S_1)\in X$.

---

Is there $(f,S)\in X$ such that $\{x\in S\mid f(x)\neq 0\}$ does not have measure zero?

Comment: Sure: Just take constant function equal 1 on an open bounded subset whose boundary has positive measure.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you very much for your answer!